# Openfire: Granular alerts

Tags: alerts, openfire

Our organization has had an Openfire server up and running for about a year now. So far we have used it for messaging in the I.T. Dept and Alerts to all users. We hit a snag this week when one system went down and several notifications were sent out to inform users of progress. Some of the users were Radiologists that do not use the particular system in question and these users found it more of an annoyance than informative. Since that I have been tasked with finding a more granular system for alerts. 
I am confident that Openfire can handle this and I have just about settled on a way of getting this to work. My idea is to create a half dozen or so users. For example: Staff, Doctor, Assitant and Supervisor. Using spark as our messenger has worked great so far so I would like to stick with that if possible. With that in mind, under advanced login features the resource name can be changed to something unique and non-unique users can log in under the same account, however, when a message is sent to one of these users, the message delivery is inconsistent. Currently I have 4 users under the Assistant user and it seems only 1 of the users receives the messages. 
Is this scenario even possible? I am avoiding working with the groups in Openfire because the function is atrocious. I could possibly integrate the system into our Active directory but I don’t think that will get us to a workable solution any quicker or more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Using group chats would be much, ***much*** cleaner as a notification system than trying to shoehorn and duct tape broadcast functionality together by logging multiple users in under the same account.  What problems do you have with the group chat functionality?

If you do want to continue pursuing this approach, you'll want to set up the `route-all.resources` setting in OpenFire - that should get you on the right path.